# A valuable 'Riley riddle'

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix has a value when defined,
>
> My infix has value when it's refined.
>
> My suffix is not usually moved,
>
> My whole is after something's been removed.

**What am I?**

Hint 1:

> If you steal my infix, you may end up at my suffix.

Hint 2:

> Same answer but not necessarily the same prefix/suffix/infix:
>
>  *My prefix does not play but is part of the game,*
>  *My suffix is a place for passengers of a train.*
>  *My infix is shouted as warning of danger overhead,*
>  *My whole can make a specific type of bed.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Reforestation

My prefix has a value when defined

> Ref is a reference wrapper in C++.

My infix has value when it's refined

> Ore is a naturally occurring solid material from which a metal or valuable mineral can be extracted profitably.

My suffix is not usually moved

> A station is usually fixed by definition.

My whole is after something's been removed

> Reforestation is the planting of a forest after being removed.

**Hint 1**

If you steal my infix, you may end up at my suffix

> I think this means that the clearing of a *forest* can lead to the building of a *station*.

**Hint 2**

My prefix does not play but is part of the game

> Ref is short for referee

My suffix is a place for passengers of a train

> Station (as in train station)

My infix is shouted as warning of danger overhead

> Golfers shout 'Fore' to warn about their incoming shots

My whole can make a specific type of bed

> A seed-bed

Comment: This sounds plausible, but I think you have one letter too many in your first infix.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan okay I'm willing to accept that. Do you think the same reasoning applies?

Comment: The answer is correct but the first infix is incorrect. @GarethMcCaughan is correct in there being one too many letters. The reasoning should require no wordplay. The first hint has a different reasoning as well.

Comment: Ah, sorry! I thought @GarethMcCaughan was talking about the other letter. I've edited my answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I think this isn't the answer, but I've come up so far with

> Impastation

My prefix has a value when defined

> **Im** - by definition, imaginary numbers have a value when an "imaginary number" is defined, otherwise we cannot assign value to them

My infix has value when it's refined

> **pas** - para-aminosalicylic acid, used for creating a drug to treat tuberculosis. Otherwise has no "value" to us.

My suffix is not usually moved & Hint 1

> **Stations** aren't usually moved. Also because of the 1st hint: *If you steal my infix, you may end up at my suffix* means that you'll end up at the police station upon the accusation of theft.

My whole is after something's been removed

> Making a paste out of something usually means that you'll get rid of components which would ruin its texture.

Comment: Not bad, the suffix is correct as long as the reason behind the first hint. Nice interpretation for the other 2.

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is:

> carbondioxide (CO2)

My prefix has a value when defined

> You can put a number before it. It then has a value.

My infix has value when it's refined

> Refined Carbon is diamond

My suffix is not usually moved

> Suffix is dioxide. Oxygen isn't usually moved

My whole is after something's been removed

> If Oxygen is removed (breathing) you get CO2

Hint 1

If you steal my infix, you may end up at my suffix

> Trees remove carbon(dioxide) from the air and add oxygen

I know it's not a perfect solution. My answer was posted before he added the second hit.

Comment: Nice answer but there are a few issues. Carbon dioxide can be achieved by removing hydrogen, not oxygen. I am not sure how Oxygen is not moved, it is primarily a gas and is always moving.

So this is not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @wolfram42 You remove oxygen when breathing which creates carbondioxide. I knew the moving of oxygen wasn't correct, but the other things were so I wanted to add it anyway.

Comment: The breathing reaction is 6O2 + C6H12O6 = 6CO2 + 6H2O so it depends on your perspective. I can see how that could be removal, but I think of it as addition. Since you are removing oxygen from the carbohydrate.